# How do I update a file using an ArrayList, Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a method that will take in some command line arguments, validate them and if valid will edit an airport's code. The airport name and it's code are stored in a CSV file. An example is "Belfast,BHD". The command line arguments are entered as follows, java editAirport EA BEL Belfast, "EA" is the 2letter code that makes the project know that I want to Edit the code for an Airport, "BEL" is the new code, and Belfast is the name of the Airport.
When I have checked through the cla's and validated them I read through the file and store them in an ArrayList as, "Belfast,BEL". Then I want to update the text file by removing the lines from the text file and dumping in the arraylist, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone show me a way using simple code (no advanced java stuff) how this is possible.
Here is my program

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    public class editAirport
    {
      public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
      {
        String pattern = "[A-Z]{3}";
        String line, line1, line2;
        String[] parts;
        String[] parts1;
        boolean found1 = false, found2 = false;
        File file = new File("Airports.txt"); // I created the file using the examples in the outline
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(file);
        String x = args[0], y = args[1], z = args[2];
        //-------------- Validation -------------------------------
        if(args.length != 3) // if user enters more or less than 3 CLA's didplay message
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usage: java editAirport EA AirportCode(3 letters) AirportName");
        else if(!(file.exists())) // if "Airports.txt" doesn't exist end program
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Airports.txt does not exist");
        else // if everything is hunky dory
        {
          if(!(x.equals("EA"))) //if user doesn't enter EA an message will be displayed
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usage: java editAirport EA AirportCode(3 letters) AirportName");
          else if(!(y.matches(pattern))) // If the code doesn't match the pattern a message will be dislayed
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Airport Code is invalid");

          while(in.hasNext())
          {
             line = in.nextLine();
             parts = line.split(",");
             if(y.equalsIgnoreCase(parts[1]))
                found1 = true;  //checking if Airport code already is in use
             if(z.equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0]))
                found2 = true; // checking if Airport name is in the file
          }
          if(found1)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Airport Code already exists, Enter a different one.");
          else if(found2 = false)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Airport Name not found, Enter it again."); 
          else

            /*
            Creating the ArrayList to store the name,code.
            1st while adds the names and coses to arraylist, 
            checks if the name of the airport that is being edited is  in the line,
            then it adds the new code onto the name.
            sorting the arraylist.
            2nd for/while is printing the arraylist into the file
            */
            ArrayList<String> airport = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(in1.hasNext()) // 1st while
            {
                line1 = in1.nextLine();
                if(line1.contains(z))
                {
                    parts1 = line1.split(",");
                    parts1[1] = y;
                    airport.add(parts1[0] + "," + parts1[1]);
                }
                else
                    airport.add(line1);
            }
            Collections.sort(airport); // sorts arraylist
            FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
            for(int i = 0; i < airport.size();)
            {
                while(in2.hasNext()) // 2nd while
                {
                    line2 = in2.nextLine();
                    line2 = airport.get(i);
                    output.println(line2);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            output.close();
            aFileWriter.close();    
        }   
    }
}
```

}

The Airports.txt file is this

```
    Aberdeen,ABZ
    Belfast City,BHD 
    Dublin,DUB 
    New York,JFK 
    Shannon,SNN 
    Venice,VCE
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "can someone show me the code" homework-dump type question.

Comment: how is this off-topic!! I need help with a serious problem I have been having for a couple of days, and I cannot find any solutions anywhere

Comment: The confusion here might be the large comment in your code that looks a lot like the old "fill this bit in for me, plz!!!" that many people do. In fact, you have implemented it in the lines below - you have a legitimate question here, it's just a bit hard to understand :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I just have it commented so that people can understand what is happening, I put the large comment in the last else as there is a lot happening in that else. and to not have big long comments on the side.

Comment: My major problem is also in the final Else, when I am attempting to print out the arraylist, I'm just adding it onto the end of the code, and not updating it

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may lie in the two lines:

```
line2 = in2.nextLine();
line2 = airport.get(i);
```

this will overwrite the 'line2' in memory, but not in the file.

Comment: Yeah, is there a way to overwrite the actual line in the file

Comment: Not in the way you seem to be trying to do it - you can't just say "set line x to value s". You have to write out the whole file again, and where you get to the line you want to replace, print that line instead of the one you just read.

Comment: Let me put it this way : you are reading in values (say) [a, b, c, d, e, f...] and you want to change "c" to "p", so you write out [a, b, *p*, d, e, f...] - it's almost doing it already. (oh, and you might want to call "output.flush()"?).

Comment: Well I have them all correct and in order in the arraylist, so how do I print out the data in the arraylist (i'm guessing a for loop) into the file, I just can't understand how to do it. Sorry if it is annoying, I'm still only learning Java

Comment: Sorry, misread your code. Then you really just want to write to the output file without bothering to read it first - you then will just overwrite whatever values are in the file with the values in your Airport list.

Comment: I tried doing that but it just added it onto the file, it didn't update the file